# Get Auth Laravel Data to populate using Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

How do I populate `auth()->user()->first_name` or `{{ optional(auth()->user()->first_name) }}` from my blade

Populate it using vue.js `file.js` to `user.first_name` code below?

```
var app = new Vue({
   el: '#property-booking',
    data: {
      user: {
        first_name: '',
        ......somecodes
      },
...Somecodes
```

**Note: my.blade.php & vuefile.js file is separated**

Comment: What you want is to pass user data from blade to vue component?

Comment: If it is possible. That's what I'm trying to do or to get the laravel auth data and pass it to vuejs

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html).

This [post](https://medium.com/js-dojo/properly-passing-data-from-laravel-blade-to-vue-components-57689b43d7fc) may help you.

```php
// blade

<component-name user={{ json_encode(auth()->user()) }}/>
```

```js
var app = new Vue({
   el: '#property-booking',
   props: ['user']
...Somecodes
```

and use in your component like `user.first_name`, `user.some_attribute`

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi, where I gonna put `user.first_name` ? Because I was trying to put data on my `first_name: ' ',` located on my `vuefile.js`